# Add Password to regex expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I'm having regular expression which is checking if password is having at least one number one upper one lower.

Now we want to add "Password" should not be used in password. i'm not getting how i can add this existing regular expression.

here is the regex:

```
@"^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,128}$"
```

Please help me.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just check if password `Contains` "Password"?

Comment: Don't make things complex. Ruling out every simple exception is easier for maintenence.